# Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'setupuser' available as request attribute

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, modelattribute

I was trying to develop a web application using Spring Framework on Tomcat 8.0 Server however, I am stuck on this error. Other two form pages are able to bind the data in the form by using ModelAttribute however, the third from which is userprofile.jsp is throwing up errors "***Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'setupuser' available as request attribute***". Kindly help me to get rid of this error. Thanks

**Error -**

```
Jan 18, 2016 4:32:12 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.InputTag doStartTag
SEVERE: Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'setupuser' available as request attribute
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'setupuser' available as request attribute
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.support.BindStatus.<init>(BindStatus.java:144)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.getBindStatus(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:179)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.getPropertyPath(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:199)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.getName(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:165)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.autogenerateId(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:152)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.resolveId(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:143)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.writeDefaultAttributes(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:127)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractHtmlElementTag.writeDefaultAttributes(AbstractHtmlElementTag.java:421)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.InputTag.writeTagContent(InputTag.java:142)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractFormTag.doStartTagInternal(AbstractFormTag.java:103)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.RequestContextAwareTag.doStartTag(RequestContextAwareTag.java:80)
    at org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.views.userprofile_jsp._jspx_meth_form_005finput_005f0(userprofile_jsp.java:386)
    at org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.views.userprofile_jsp._jspService(userprofile_jsp.java:168)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:438)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:396)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:340)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:291)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:719)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:465)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:390)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:317)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceView.renderMergedOutputModel(InternalResourceView.java:238)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractView.render(AbstractView.java:264)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1201)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:986)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:933)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:851)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:953)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:855)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:648)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:829)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:291)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:212)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:141)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:616)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:521)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1096)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:674)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1500)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1456)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

Jan 18, 2016 4:32:12 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet jsp threw exception
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'setupuser' available as request attribute
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.support.BindStatus.<init>(BindStatus.java:144)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.getBindStatus(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:179)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.getPropertyPath(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:199)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.getName(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:165)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.autogenerateId(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:152)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.resolveId(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:143)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.writeDefaultAttributes(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:127)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractHtmlElementTag.writeDefaultAttributes(AbstractHtmlElementTag.java:421)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.InputTag.writeTagContent(InputTag.java:142)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractFormTag.doStartTagInternal(AbstractFormTag.java:103)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.RequestContextAwareTag.doStartTag(RequestContextAwareTag.java:80)
    at org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.views.userprofile_jsp._jspx_meth_form_005finput_005f0(userprofile_jsp.java:386)
    at org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.views.userprofile_jsp._jspService(userprofile_jsp.java:168)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:438)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:396)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:340)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:291)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:719)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:465)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:390)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:317)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceView.renderMergedOutputModel(InternalResourceView.java:238)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractView.render(AbstractView.java:264)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1201)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:986)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:933)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:851)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:953)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:855)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:648)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:829)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:291)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:212)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:141)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:616)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:521)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1096)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:674)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1500)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1456)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

Jan 18, 2016 4:32:12 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [onlineEnrollment] in context with path [/onlineEnrollment] threw exception [An exception occurred processing JSP page /WEB-INF/views/userprofile.jsp at line 17

14: <b>Setup your contact information:</b> <br />
15: 
16: <form:form method="POST" modelAttribute="setupuser">
17: EMAIL ADDRESS:  <form:input path="email" /> <br />
18: <form:errors path="email" cssStyle="" cssClass="color:red;" /><br />
19: CONFIRM EMAIL ADDRESS: <form:input path="confirmEmail" /> <br />
20: <form:errors path="confirmEmail" cssClass="color:red;" /><br /><br />


Stacktrace:] with root cause
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'setupuser' available as request attribute
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.support.BindStatus.<init>(BindStatus.java:144)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.getBindStatus(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:179)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.getPropertyPath(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:199)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.getName(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:165)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.autogenerateId(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:152)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.resolveId(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:143)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.writeDefaultAttributes(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:127)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractHtmlElementTag.writeDefaultAttributes(AbstractHtmlElementTag.java:421)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.InputTag.writeTagContent(InputTag.java:142)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractFormTag.doStartTagInternal(AbstractFormTag.java:103)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.RequestContextAwareTag.doStartTag(RequestContextAwareTag.java:80)
    at org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.views.userprofile_jsp._jspx_meth_form_005finput_005f0(userprofile_jsp.java:386)
    at org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.views.userprofile_jsp._jspService(userprofile_jsp.java:168)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:438)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:396)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:340)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:291)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:719)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:465)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:390)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:317)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceView.renderMergedOutputModel(InternalResourceView.java:238)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractView.render(AbstractView.java:264)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1201)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:986)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:933)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:851)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:953)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:855)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:648)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:829)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:291)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:212)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:141)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:616)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:521)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1096)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:674)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1500)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1456)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

**OptionalServicesController.java -**

```
package com.banking.onlineenrollment.controller;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;
import com.banking.onlineenrollment.service.UserService;
import com.banking.onlineenrollment.user.UserAgreementForm;

@Controller
@RequestMapping(value = "/optional.do")
public class OptionalServicesController {

private UserService userService;

    @Autowired
    public OptionalServicesController(UserService userService) {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        this.userService = userService;
    }

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView displayOptionalServices() {
        ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView("optionalservices");
        UserAgreementForm userAgreementForm = new UserAgreementForm();
        mv.addObject("optionalservices", userAgreementForm);
        return mv;
    }

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ModelAndView processOptionalServices(@ModelAttribute("optionalservices") UserAgreementForm userAgreementForm) {
        ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView();
        userService.saveOptionalServices(userAgreementForm.getEnrollServices(), userAgreementForm.getVerifyServices());
        mv.setViewName("userprofile");
        return mv;
    }
}
```

**userprofile.jsp**

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Setup User Profile</title>
</head>
<body>
<h3>4.Setup User Profile</h3>
The following is required to complete your user profile.<br /><c:out value="${message}"></c:out><br /><br />
<b>Setup your contact information:</b> <br />

<form:form method="POST" modelAttribute="setupuser">
EMAIL ADDRESS:  <form:input path="email" /> <br />
<form:errors path="email" cssStyle="" cssClass="color:red;" /><br />
CONFIRM EMAIL ADDRESS: <form:input path="confirmEmail" /> <br />
<form:errors path="confirmEmail" cssClass="color:red;" /><br /><br />
<b>Setup your username and password:</b><br />
USERNAME:  <form:input path="username" /> <br />
<form:errors path="username" cssClass="color:red;" /><br />
PASSWORD:  <form:password path="password" /> <br />
<form:errors path="password" cssClass="color:red;" /><br />
CONFIRM PASSWORD:  <form:password path="confirmPassword" /> <br />
<form:errors path="confirmPassword" cssClass="color:red;" /><br />
<input type="submit" value="Continue"> <br /><br />

Password Complexity Requirements
Your password cannot contain your username.
Your password must be a minimum of 8 characters and must
meet at least 3 of the following 4 categories:
English uppercase characters (A - Z)
English lowercase characters (a - z)
Numeric digits (0 - 9)
Non-alphanumeric (For example: !, $, #, or %)
Passwords are case sensitive. For added security we
recommend that you change your password every 90 days.
</form:form>
</body>
</html>
```

**UserProfileController.java**

```
    /**
     * 
     */
    package com.banking.onlineenrollment.controller;


    import javax.validation.Valid;

    import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
    import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
    import org.springframework.validation.BindingResult;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
    import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;
    import com.banking.onlineenrollment.service.UserService;
    import com.banking.onlineenrollment.user.UserProfileForm;

    /**
     * @author Harsh
     *
     */
    @Controller
    @RequestMapping(value = "/userprofile.do")
    public class UserProfileController {
        private UserService userService;

        @Autowired
        public UserProfileController(UserService userService) {
            // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
            this.userService = userService;
        }

        @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
        public ModelAndView displayUserProfile() {
            ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView("userprofile");
            UserProfileForm userProfileForm = new UserProfileForm();
            mv.addObject("setupuser", userProfileForm);
            return mv;
        }

        @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
        public ModelAndView processUserProfile(@Valid @ModelAttribute("setupuser") UserProfileForm userProfileForm, BindingResult result) { 
            System.out.println("Inside POST method beginning of userprofile");
            ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView();
            if(result.hasErrors()) {
                mv.setViewName("userprofile");
                mv.addObject("message", "Don't leave the form blank");
            }
            else {
                userService.saveUserProfile(userProfileForm.getEmail(),userProfileForm.getConfirmEmail(),userProfileForm.getUsername(),userProfileForm.getPassword(), userProfileForm.getConfirmPassword());
                mv.setViewName("securityprofile");
            }
            return mv;
        }
    }
```

**UserService.java**

```
package com.banking.onlineenrollment.service;

/**
 * @author Harsh
 *
 */
public interface UserService {
    public int isValid(String idType, int idNum, String token);
    public void saveOptionalServices(int enrollServices, int verifyServices);
    public void saveUserProfile(String email, String confirmEmail, String username, String password, String confirmPassword);
    public void saveSecurityProfile(int q1, String a1, int q2, String a2,
            int q3, String a3, int q4, String a4 );
}
```

**UserAgreementForm.java**

```
package com.banking.onlineenrollment.user;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
@Component
public class UserAgreementForm {

    private int enrollServices;

    private int verifyServices;
    public int getEnrollServices() {
        return enrollServices;
    }

    public void setEnrollServices(int enrollServices) {
        this.enrollServices = enrollServices;
    }

    public int getVerifyServices() {
        return verifyServices;
    }

    public void setVerifyServices(int verifyServices) {
        this.verifyServices = verifyServices;
    }

}
```

**Web.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
            http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
            http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
    version="3.0">

<display-name>onlineEnrollment</display-name>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>

  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>onlineEnrollment</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
  <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>    

  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>onlineEnrollment</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.do</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

**UserProfileForm**

```
/**
 * 
 */
package com.banking.onlineenrollment.user;

import javax.validation.constraints.Size;

import org.hibernate.validator.constraints.Email;
import org.hibernate.validator.constraints.NotBlank;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

/**
 * @author Harsh
 *
 */
@Component
public class UserProfileForm {
    @NotBlank
    @Size(min = 5, max = 20)
    @Email
    private String email;
    @NotBlank
    @Size(min = 5, max = 20)
    @Email
    private String confirmEmail;
    @NotBlank
    @Size(min = 5, max = 20)
    private String username;
    @NotBlank
    private String password;
    @NotBlank
    private String confirmPassword;

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public String getConfirmEmail() {
        return confirmEmail;
    }

    public void setConfirmEmail(String confirmEmail) {
        this.confirmEmail = confirmEmail;
    }

    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    public String getConfirmPassword() {
        return confirmPassword;
    }

    public void setConfirmPassword(String confirmPassword) {
        this.confirmPassword = confirmPassword;
    }


}
```

Comment: I'm interested to help but first you need to share the `UserService`, `UserAgreementForm`, and `web.xml` so that I can try it. :P

Comment: Hello onion, I have updated my question so now you can have a look at those files. Thanks.

Comment: Hello, it's still missing `UserProfileForm` class, then how could I fixed that for you (-___"

Comment: @onion I've added that file now as well

Comment: hello, are you there?? I've answered it please try it.

Answer (score 0):

You can try annotating the request mapping on the function level instead of class level :

but first add

```
<mvc:annotation-driven />
```

to your *`onlineEnrollment-servlet.xml`*

and also `xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"` on the top `<beans ...>` declaration in your *`onlineEnrollment-servlet.xml`*

now try to change the controller methods (just copy all exactly to your codes) to :

```
  package com.banking.onlineenrollment.controller;
    import javax.validation.Valid;

    import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
    import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
    import org.springframework.validation.BindingResult;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
    import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;
    import com.banking.onlineenrollment.service.UserService;
    import com.banking.onlineenrollment.user.UserProfileForm;

    /**
     * @author Harsh
     *
     */
    @Controller
//    @RequestMapping(value = "/userprofile.do")
    public class UserProfileController {
        private UserService userService;

        @Autowired
        public UserProfileController(UserService userService) {
            // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
            this.userService = userService;
        }

        @RequestMapping(value="/askform.do",method = RequestMethod.GET)
        public ModelAndView displayUserProfile() {
            ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView("userprofile");
            UserProfileForm userProfileForm = new UserProfileForm();
            mv.addObject("setupuser", userProfileForm);
            return mv;
        }

        @RequestMapping(value="/populateformfield.do",method = RequestMethod.POST)
        public ModelAndView processUserProfile(@Valid @ModelAttribute("setupuser") UserProfileForm userProfileForm, BindingResult result) { 
            System.out.println("Inside POST method beginning of userprofile");
            ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView();
            if(result.hasErrors()) {
                mv.setViewName("userprofile");
                mv.addObject("message", "Don't leave the form blank");
            }
            else {
                userService.saveUserProfile(userProfileForm.getEmail(),userProfileForm.getConfirmEmail(),userProfileForm.getUsername(),userProfileForm.getPassword(), userProfileForm.getConfirmPassword());
                mv.setViewName("securityprofile");
            }
            return mv;
        }
    }
```

And now change `userProfile.jsp` to :

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
         pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
        <title>Setup User Profile</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h3>4.Setup User Profile</h3>
        The following is required to complete your user profile.<br /><c:out value="${message}"></c:out><br /><br />
    <b>Setup your contact information:</b> <br />

    <form:form method="POST" modelAttribute="setupuser" action="populateformfield.do">
        EMAIL ADDRESS:  <form:input path="email" /> <br />
        <form:errors path="email" cssStyle="" cssClass="color:red;" /><br />
        CONFIRM EMAIL ADDRESS: <form:input path="confirmEmail" /> <br />
        <form:errors path="confirmEmail" cssClass="color:red;" /><br /><br />
        <b>Setup your username and password:</b><br />
        USERNAME:  <form:input path="username" /> <br />
        <form:errors path="username" cssClass="color:red;" /><br />
        PASSWORD:  <form:password path="password" /> <br />
        <form:errors path="password" cssClass="color:red;" /><br />
        CONFIRM PASSWORD:  <form:password path="confirmPassword" /> <br />
        <form:errors path="confirmPassword" cssClass="color:red;" /><br />
        <input type="submit" value="Continue"> <br /><br />

        Password Complexity Requirements
        Your password cannot contain your username.
        Your password must be a minimum of 8 characters and must
        meet at least 3 of the following 4 categories:
        English uppercase characters (A - Z)
        English lowercase characters (a - z)
        Numeric digits (0 - 9)
        Non-alphanumeric (For example: !, $, #, or %)
        Passwords are case sensitive. For added security we
        recommend that you change your password every 90 days.
    </form:form>
</body>
</html>
```

And now request the form with `askform.do`

Comment: I want to access userprofile.jsp from OptionalServiceController.java class from the function which takes POST request from optionalservice.jsp page. The line in processUserProfile function "mv.setViewName("userprofile");" is supposed  to display userprofile.jsp page but is unable to even after trying what you suggested above. When I directly request this page from the web browser, it works, however, it doesn't work when I try to access from optionalservices.jsp page.

Comment: The reason I annotated it on the function level because your codes contain 2 kinds of *HTTP* method (get and post), if you annotate it on the class level the request will be confused. Since you're new here you have to know that helping people that ask Spring is more or less hard *:D* , unless I get all your codes & we get some exact configuration. The common cause of why BindingResult error occurs is because *there is no binding happens* between the form and the model, that why I annotated with 2 different request url, when you request `/askform.do` then `displayUserProfile()` is executed and

Comment: -*continued:* the method will return `userprofile` form that will be bound to *setupuser*, and when you submit *userprofile* then the request changed to `/populateformfield.do` and `processUserProfile` method will be executed. So the main point is that there will *2 different requests* in binding scheme. The first is *the request for form* where binding happens & the second is *the request from the form* when you populate the form fields

Comment: I tried doing this but it is still not working, How can I call /askform.do from the submit button of the previous page which in turn saves some data and then displays userprofile form page ?.